# Link to search filters by price only

Tags: magento2.3, catalogsearch

I would like to create links that will search the product catalog by price only without giving any text string.

e.g. a link like http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?price=51-100 to directly search and return those products priced between 51 and 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a category containing all products (using a dynamic category module as I'm on open source version) and then I can add the price filter to that.